# Recommendations on .NET AddIn Framework with support for AppDomain isolation

Tags: .net

I need a .NET addin framework which supports AppDomain isolation to use for our backend service processing. Essentially we will have a host service which will house multiple addins which should run in isolation and which can be individually loaded and unloaded. UI is not a primary concern as the addins are not user facing.

I've looked at a few options:

Build it myself using something like MEF (or some IoC Container with scanning capabilities like Autofac or Ninject) for discovery and using AppDomain loading/unloading for isolation.
Use MAF (Managed AddIn Framework) which supports my basic needs but whose ease of use and documentation leaves something to be desired (and the required folder structure is off-putting)
The Mono.AddIn framework which seems simpler to use but does not support AppDomain Isolation out of the box. This framework however has less restrictions than MAF, but AppDomain Isolation is a must for our requirements.
Can someone provide recommendations based on their experience on what is the best way to proceed? The best of both worlds would seem to be some combination of the capabilities of Mono.AddIn and MAF, does anyone know of the existence of such a combination?

Note: Originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244701/recommendations-on-net-addin-framework-with-support-for-appdomain-isolation